# scenePhase Changes are unexpected in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I am facing a very unexpected behaviour of .scenePhase in swiftUI. I have tried with these solution but it still showing the issue [scenePhase changing unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62631554/scenephase-changing-unexpectedly) and [Not Receiving scenePhase Changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62840571/not-receiving-scenephase-changes). Here is my simple code that I am using.

```
struct TestView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Text("BackGround Changes tester")
            
        }  .onChange(of: scenePhase) { newPhase in
            switch newPhase {
                
            case .background:
                debugPrint("appMoveToBackground")
            case .inactive:
                debugPrint("appMoveToInactive")
            case .active:
                debugPrint("appMovedToForground")
            @unknown default:
                debugPrint("scenePhase: @unknown default for ")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So this is the code I am using. Sometimes it runs the .background case and sometimes it does not. Here is the console output and you can see its not running the background case, which is very unexpected.

[image: Log out put of scenePhase].

I am using Xcode 14.3, Mac OS Ventura 13.3.1 and testing it on Iphone 13 pro max.

Comment: "appMovedToForground"  This string is not included in upper switch case

Comment: appMoveToInactive called every time when the app moves to foreground to background or background to foreground. 
After that the app state will be called like if its active (move from bg to fg or start app after terminate) appMoveToActive will be print after appMoveToInactive. Or if it goes (fg to bg ) appMoveToBackground will be print right after appMoveToInactive.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
   .task(id: scenePhase) { 
        switch scenePhase {
            
        case .background:
            debugPrint("appMoveToBackground")
        case .inactive:
            debugPrint("appMoveToInactive")
        case .active:
            debugPrint("appMoveToActive")
        @unknown default:
            debugPrint("scenePhase: @unknown default for ")
        }
        
    }
```

`.task` tends to be more reliable.

Comment: this code works better just need to remove `newPhase in` in closure start

Comment: @QaziAmmar ah yes good catch i forgot to remove